# func:function return result tree fragment

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I am using Xalan-j 2.7.1. I have written a function using xalans implementation of exslt func:function extensions. I am trying to make my xslt cleaner by using repeatable portion of output xml into functions. The following function is a representation of what I am trying to do.

The expected output is a xml tree fragment but I am not seeing any output. I dont know why this doesn't work though it is mentioned in exslt.org documentation

xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
   xmlns:common="http://exslt.org/common"
   xmlns:my="http://my.org/my"
   exclude-result-prefixes="func common my"> 
   <xsl:output type="xml" indent="yes" /> 

   <func:function name="my:personinfo"> 
       <xsl:param name="name" /> 
       <xsl:param name="address" /> 
    <func:result>
       <xsl:element name="details"> 
            <xsl:element name="name" select="$name" />
            <xsl:element name="address" select="$address" />  
       </xsl:element>          
    </func:result> 
   </func:function> 

   <xsl:element name="results">
         <xsl:value-of select="my:personinfo('john', '02-234 pudding lane, london')" />
   </xsl:element> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can I ask why? Why use an XSLT 1.0 processor with half-baked extension functions to give it a small amount of the extra capability of XSLT 2.0, when you could be using the real thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have nodes in a result tree fragment and want to output them to the result tree you need to use `<xsl:copy-of select="my:personinfo('john', '02-234 pudding lane, london')"/>`, not `value-of`.

Note however that `xsl:element` does not take a `select` attribute, if you want to create elements either simply use literal result elements like

```
<details>
  <name><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></name>
  <address><xsl:value-of select="$address"/></address>
</details>
```

or if you want to use `xsl:element` make sure you populate elements with the proper syntax e.g.

```
<xsl:element name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></xsl:element>
```

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering the question. "<xsl:copy-of select="" /> really works !